# How to set asidebar fixed on right side and left side content scroll?

Tags: html, css

I need aside bar fixed on the right side and only left side content can scroll.

I tried below code but it's not working. I am getting the right side div on top because of `position: fixed.`. Can anyone check my code and assist me.
Would you help me out on this issue?

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header></header>
    <div class="banner_bg wrapper_header">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper_content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="widget-area">
        <aside>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>        
</aside>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**style**

```
body,html{padding:0;margin: 0;height: 100%;}
    .wrapper_header{
        background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1596574/pexels-photo-1596574.jpeg');
        position:relative;
        background-position: center;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .banner_bg{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;width:100%;height:auto;min-height:100%;}
aside
{
    position:fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
    .wrapper_content{padding: 50px 0;}
    .widget-area{
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow:0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        padding: 20px;
        border:1px solid #eee;
    }
```

I am getting output

[image]

I need an output like this. so that only left content scroll and right will be fixed.

[image]

Comment: aside
{
    position:fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}  remove this style. it will work

Comment: @KesavanR but aside will not be fixed if I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the Aside CSS that you have in there, it's just causing the conflict you're experiencing.

https://codepen.io/robert9111/pen/PxQXBd

For record i removed

```
/* aside {
    position:fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
} */
```

and I'm getting your desired output.

Comment: If I comment aside css then it will get my output but it not complete output I need a fixed div so that if anyone scrolls the page then it will scroll only the left content not right.

Comment: I've updated my Codepen. You are targeting the wrong element in your CSS.

Instead of targeting the Aside, target the widget area as that's what you'll want to stay in 1 place and follow you down the screen. You'll need some additional Javascript to make sure it starts to become fixed instead of relative. (Position: relative to Position:Fixed)

Comment: The content Which I shared on the left side that is dummy text, That will increase in future. Now I am getting the fixed div on the header section which I don't want. aside div should be fixed in the class of wrapper_content only. I need my aside div only here http://prntscr.com/llh1c3   .. if someone scroll then it will scroll only left content.

Comment: Can you confirm you've seen my updated codepen? It's the same one as in my original answer. 

As i stated, You'll need JS/Jquery to make sure the div becomes "position:fixed" instead of "position: relative" once it enters the viewport or else it will float all the way to the top of the screen as it is fixed to a certain position within the page.

Comment: Yes, I checked your updated code.I need like this https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/examples/basic.html but I need on right side

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for affix from bootstrap.

[affix bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#affix)

For your problem the solution is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
body,html{padding:0;margin: 0;height: 100%;}
    .wrapper_header{
        background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1596574/pexels-photo-1596574.jpeg');
        position:relative;
        background-position: center;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .banner_bg{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;width:100%;height:auto;min-height:100%;}
    .wrapper_content{padding: 50px 0;}
    .widget-area{
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow:0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        padding: 20px;
        border:1px solid #eee;
    }
    
    .affix{
        right: 16%;
        width: 400px;
        top: 5%;
    }
    
    // bootstrap will add affix-top and affix-botttom class as well we can use if required 
    
    </style>
<header></header>
    <div class="banner_bg wrapper_header">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper_content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="720" >
    <div class="widget-area"  >
        <aside>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>        
</aside>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Just add **data-spy="affix"** **data-offset-top="720"** into your sidebar container. and add style for **affix**

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I need like this abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/examples/basic.html but I need on right side

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```css
body, html {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper_header {
        background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1596574/pexels-photo-1596574.jpeg');
        position: relative;
        background-position: center;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        height: 400px;
    }

    .banner_bg {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
    }

    aside {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .fixedElement {
        position: relative;
    }

    .wrapper_content {
        padding: 50px 0;
    }

    .widget-area {
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header></header>
<div class="banner_bg wrapper_header">
</div>
<div class="wrapper_content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 anchor">
                <aside class="fixedElement">
                    <div class="widget-area ">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                    </div>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        var $el = $('.fixedElement');
        var anchor = $('.anchor');
        var anchor = anchor.offset().top;
        var windowTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        var diff = windowTop - anchor;
        if (diff > 0) {
            $el.css({'top': diff + 'px'});
        } else {
            $el.css({'top': '0px'});
        }
    });
</script>
```